# Nest can't resolve dependencies of the ....Please make sure that the argument .. at index [0] is available in the

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, nestjs

I have:

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { InjectModel } from '@nestjs/sequelize';
import { Conversation } from './conversation.model'
import { FindConversationsDto } from '../dto/conversations.find'

@Injectable()
export class ConversationsService {
    constructor(
        @InjectModel(Conversation)
        private conversationModel: typeof Conversation
    ) { }

    async findConversations(queryParams: FindConversationsDto): Promise<Conversation[]> {
        return new Promise((resolve) => [])
        // return await this.conversationModel.findAll();


    }
}
```

And I get this weird error:

```
Nest can't resolve dependencies of the ConversationsService (?). Please make sure that the argument ConversationRepository at index [0] is available in the ConversationsModule context.

Potential solutions:
- If ConversationRepository is a provider, is it part of the current ConversationsModule?
- If ConversationRepository is exported from a separate @Module, is that module imported within ConversationsModule?
  @Module({
    imports: [ /* the Module containing ConversationRepository */ ]
  })
```

`ConversationModule` is:

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ConversationsController } from './conversations.controller';
import { ConversationsService } from './conversations.service';

@Module({
  controllers: [ConversationsController],
  providers: [ConversationsService]
})
export class ConversationsModule {}
```

Not sure what `ConversationRepository` is referring to.

Comment: Can you show your `ConversationModule` file well?

Comment: Updated with `ConversationModule`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to add in the `SequelizeModule.forFeature()` to your `ConversationModule`'s `imports` array, to tell Nest that in the context of this module, I have access to the `ConversationRepository`. The terminology is borrowed from TypeORM, as with TypeO you have Entities and Repositories, but whereas with Sequelize you have Models and Tables, but the ideas are the same overall. Your `ConverstationModule` should *probably* look something like this:

```js
@Module({
  imports: [SequelizeModule.forFeature([Conversation])],
  providers: [ConversationService],
  controllers: [ConversationController]
})
export class ConversationModule {}
```

Comment: I have `autoLoadModels: true` in my DB loader. Do I still need to import the models in each Module?

Comment: Yes, it is needed for nestjs.

Comment: Yes. [Quote from the docs](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/database#auto-load-models): "Note that models that aren't registered through the forFeature() method, but are only referenced from the model (via an association), won't be included. "